# Raspberry Pi getting burningly hot and not displaying

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues, rip

I tried turning on my raspberry pi 3 b+ and it wouldn't show anything to my TV, the entire Pi ( mainly around the SD card ) was so hot I could barely touch it. Bare in mind the pi was only on for about 1 minute. Could it have been shorted?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you had connected to your Pi?

Comment: If anything on your RPi gets too hot to touch very quickly then you have damaged it beyond repair. The usual cause is GPIO abuse (including wiring things to GPIO pins with the power on).

Comment: Hi, @No Copywrite Spectrums, Welcome! Ah let me see.  This morning I booted up my Rpi4B. Now 45 minutes later and I tried to touch the high quality, expensive (3 Yuans!) elegant copper (not cheapie aluminium) heat sink sitting on top of the cpu and found I could only barely hold it for 5 seconds (yes, I used the stop watch in my little head to time my endurance). What I am trying to say is that Rpi4B processor is finger burning hot even working normally.  In other words, it might still be alive, though hot like on fire, and screaming for water.

Answer (score 2):

i've had a further look at it. My RP3's SD card had popped and split in half. Turns out i'm not the only one. There's a lot of people online that have had the same issue as me. They take it down after months, turn it on. And within a minute its unbareable to touch

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that some connections in your rpi is shorted somehow.
It seems your board is not working again so I am leaving some suggestions for others. Always clean your raspberry pi with a brush. The main problem of unused raspberry pi is they have dust on them and conductor particles can easily burn everything if not cleaned properly.