# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ won't boot up after 1 week of use

Tags: boot, sd-card, pi-3b+

So I just got a new raspberry pi 3 b+ earlier this week by RS Components and I got it working on the first day. A couple days I shut it down and later when I tried to turn it back on, it didn't all it shows is the red led indicating the power, not the green ACT light. I tried re-flashing my 16gb SD card with NOOBS again. What should I do? (I have tried 
[The boot problems sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) . It is not hot and I have used the GPIO pins during the week.

**UPDATE** I have just decided to say it is broken. I may have over-voltaged it and if anyone knows if RS components does replacements can you tell me

Comment: so, when you power it on, nothing at all on the screen either?

Comment: Yes, all it says is 'no signal'

Comment: it's probably dead - does it get hot like in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105355/raspberry-pi-getting-burningly-hot-and-not-displaying)

Comment: no it does not, it never gets 'hot'. and what would be considered hot for it to be dead.

Comment: well, hot as in too hot to touch like in the question I linked to - during the week of use what did you physically do with it? i.e. did you use the GPIO pins? Was it in a case or did you just have the bare pi sitting around?

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but how exactly would i have **killed** it?

Comment: I did use the GPIO pins and it was not in a case. The pi is barely even warm.

Comment: I don't know, I have 13 pi's of various flavours and never killed one - I wasn't there during the week of you using the pi, so no idea what you may have done - have you tried a different SD card

Comment: No, I will try using a different SD card and I will get back to you thanks. Do you recommend a size?

Comment: micro-sd is the only size that fits :p - for testing 8GB will do you

Comment: thanks, but when i said size i meant 8gb, 16,gb, 32gb

Comment: If you have a multimeter measure the voltage between pin#17 and the outer shield of the USB connector (should be `3.3V`). Then measure the voltage between pin#4 and the USB connector (should be `5V`). If the `3.3V` isn't there then your Raspberry is dead as the power supply chip has died.

Comment: sorry, I don't, is there an alternative to check if it is dead?

Comment: *I did use the GPIO pins* - in what way?

Comment: I used 8 LED bulbs so i used 8 gpio pins and 8 ground pins

Comment: Please make your Update an answer and accept it after two days. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I did not have enough power and I was using a lot of the pins. I also may have accidentally damaged something as well. I have decided to get a refund (which was successful) and just buy a new one from canakit. I will try to be more careful. Usually, Amazon is good with returns.

Answer (score 0):

You **Don't** flash a SD card with [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) you **have** to format the SD card then copy NOOBS on to it.

NOTE this is harder, takes longer, wastes 1.3GB of your SD card and is almost impossible to update, which is why most of us **DON'T** use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)

NOTE the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) doesn't really apply to NOOBS - it is geared at Raspbian boot problems.

Comment: sorry, i meant that. I did format it using 'SD card formatter'